# Three masses on a circle connected by spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, spring, coupled-oscillators

How would I go about finding the normal modes of three masses on a circular hoop, with springs connecting them across the circle, in a triangle (assume the spring constants and masses are the same). I know that it's a common problem to find the oscillations if the springs are also threaded on the hoop, but it seems to be a lot more complicated if the springs are connecting them across the circle, and not along it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get you started.

It's not as bad as you might think at first glance.  I think it's easiest to see how to proceed using vector notation.  Let $\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2, \mathbf r_3$ denote the positions of the three masses in the plane containing the hoop.  Let $\ell_{ij}$ denote the length of the spring attaching mass $i$ to mass $j$, then
\begin{align}
  \ell_{ij} = |\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r_j|. 
\end{align}
Let $\ell_0$ denote the equilibrium length of each spring (which we assume to be identically constructed), then the potential energy in the spring connecting mass $i$ to mass $j$ is
\begin{align}
  U_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}k(\ell_{ij} - \ell_0)^2
\end{align}
where $k$ is the spring constant of each spring.  Try taking it from here.